# How to choose on which port the server starts ( linux )?

Tags: c, linux

I have this simple server C based code. I want to manually input from the command line using argv the port. How should I do this? I have no ideea where and what to modify to change the default port because I recently started using linux.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: You dont know how to use argv or where to modify in program?
Question is showing no research on your part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign **argv[1]** to **serv_addr.sin_port**

```
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
```

By this you can start your server at configurable port

You need to run server like

```
 ./server port
```

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO:Welcome :)

Comment: Is it possible to start the while using a string input from client(keyboard) with the message "start" and stop it with "stop"? If so... should I ask another question?

Comment: It does not compile.. the argument is of type char and it seems not to like that.